# Unable to add to JFrame after removeAll()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, addition, removeall

I have a relatively small class called "LoadingWindow" this class has a constructor that calls a Initialize function to setup the frame. Not I was testing some things to try to solve why it would not update. While testing I added "this.removeAll();" to the head of the initialize method. Turns out, I cant add anything after that. Anything I add, simply will not show.

Here is a slightly trimmed down version of the class:

```
public class LoadingWindow extends JFrame{

public JPanel panel;

public JProgressBar bar;

private JLabel label;

public LoadingWindow()
{

    this.Initialize();

}

public void Initialize()
{
    this.removeAll();

    this.setSize(300, 150);

    panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    bar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
    label = new JLabel("Please remain calm, we're just loading...");

    panel.add(bar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(label,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.add(panel);

    this.validate();
    this.repaint();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The window itself does pop up properly, with a title. However the window itself is completely blank.

I implement this class statically so that four other objects can access it in the EditorPanel class. Its defined as:

```
public static LoadingWindow loadingWindow;
```

and initialized in the constructor with:

```
loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
```

There is then a double check within the functions that use it to show it if it is hidden.

```
if(!EditorPanel.loadingWindow.isVisible()){EditorPanel.loadingWindow.Initialize();}
```

Overall I'm a bit confused as to why no content is showing, and I am very interested in any questions asked, and am willing to provide any info necessary. Google didn't provide a whole lot, and every answer I found I had already implemented "such as repaint and validate".

I look forward to hearing from you!

~Travis

Comment: notice, don't call `JFrame.removeAll()`, result could be removing the `RootPane`, empty container onle with `Toolbar` and `Borders`, use `JFrame.getContentPane().removeAll()` instead

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`removeAll()` as said by @TomHawtintackline (+1 to him), is not forwarded to the `JFrames` *contentPane*; like `add()`, `remove()` or `setLayout()` is.

Thus when you do `JFrame#removeAll()` it removes the *root pane* of `JFrame`. See [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for an interesting read and may prove fruitful for future endeavors.

You should do:

> getContentPane().removeAll();// will make sure we remove all
>   components from the contentPane

- Also dont extend `JFrame` unnecessarily (unless adding functionality beyond its current capability) rather just create an instance of `JFrame` and use that
- Dont call `setSize` rather use an appropriate `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` and return dimensions which fit drawings, thus you can call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible.
- I see no need for `validate()` and `repaint()` these should only be called when a component is added to a visible container. Even than rather do `revalidate()` which will work for adding and removing a component (it inturn calls `validate()`)

Comment: getContentPane() did indeed work. But why does the frame re appear blank after loadingWindow.setVisible(false); loadingWindow.Initialize(); ?

Comment: @TravisTruttschel please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for me to answer that accurately

Comment: +1 for "don't extend `JFrame` unnecessarily, and suggesting a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing `removeAll` removes the root pane.

`JFrame` is a container and contains a number of components that are part of what we think of as the frame. There was a hack introduced into `JFrame` (and `JApplet`), so that some methods act on the content pane instead of the frame itself. Use a different method, or one of the special methods when the forwarding is not in force, and it'll screw up.

See the API docs for `JFrame.remove` and note that `removeAll` is not overridden.

The safest solution is to ignore the "helpful" forwarding, and manipulate the content pane itself (either through `getContentPane`, or possible better create your own `JPanel` and use `setContentPane`). (Also don't extend classes, such as `JFrame` or `Thread`, unnecessarily and follow standard coding conventions.)